# Prevent TerserWebpackPlugin to remove comments at the end of script

Tags: javascript, webpack, terser-webpack-plugin

I use `TerserWebpackPlugin` with `comments: true`. But Terser removes comments after useful code - at the end of file. I would like to avoid this behavior.

```js
console.log('Example2');
//  any comments will be removed from here

/* myComment after */
// myComment after
```

How to do it?

Maybe do I need to use RegExp or callback to avoid it? But it will be difficult to support:

```js
comments?: boolean | 'all' | 'some' | RegExp | ( (node: any, comment: {
        value: string,
        type: 'comment1' | 'comment2' | 'comment3' | 'comment4',
        pos: number,
        line: number,
        col: number,
    }) => boolean );
```

Please run `build:dev` or `build:prod`.

#### File structure

- `src/index.html`
- `src/js/index.js`
- `src/scss/styles.scss` (empty)
- `package.json`
- `webpack.config.js`

#### src/js/index.js

```js
/* myComment before */
// myComment before

console.log('Example');

// myComment center
/* myComment center */

console.log('Example2');
//  any comments will be removed from here

/* myComment after */
// myComment after
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "terser-prod-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
  entry: ["./src/js/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  devtool: false,
  // mode: "production",
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          format: {
            // false - remove
            comments: true,
            beautify: true,
          },
        },
        extractComments: false,
      }),
      // '...', // works only after TerserPlugin
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scss"),
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {},
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              url: false,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              implementation: require("sass"),
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "styles.css",
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return config;
};
```

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```